# Load cell array of 2D images in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a cell array `IMAGES` with size 100-by-1, where each entry `IMAGES{i}` is a 2D array of size 32-by-32. I want to load it in Python such that the loaded variable `x` has `x.shape` return `(100L,32L,32L)`.
Right now I have written the following code:

```
imgMat = loadmat('IMAGES_DS.mat', matlab_compatible = True)

Test = imgMat ['IMAGES']

print(Test.shape[0], 'test samples')
```

Comment: I recommend to describe what variables you got in python. While many programmers around here probably know how to convert some basic data structures, only few of them are familiar with that specific function of `scipy`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the `squeeze_me` argument to `loadmat` and not the `matlab_compatible` one.  This will remove the singleton dimension in `IMAGES`, making it of shape `(100,)` rather than `(100, 1)`.

Then you should do `Test = np.dstack(Test)`, which combines the individual 32x32 arrays in IMAGES along the depth dimension (dimension 2), which will result in a `(32, 32, 100)` array.

If you really need it as a `(100, 32, 32)` array, then you can do `Test = np.rollaxis(Test, 2, 0)` to move the second dimension (the last one) to zeroth one.